# PrintWriter vs FileWriter in Java

Tags: java, filewriter, printwriter

Are PrintWriter and FileWriter in Java the same and no matter which one to use? So far I have used both because their results are the same. Is there some special cases where it makes sense to prefer one over the other?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File fpw = new File("printwriter.txt");
    File fwp = new File("filewriter.txt");
    try {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fpw);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fwp);
        pw.write("printwriter text\r\n");
        fw.write("filewriter text\r\n");
        pw.close();
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, they have different methods, and do different things. Have you read the javadoc for each one?

Comment: just remember to flush() before you close().

Comment: close ensures flush.

Comment: @Bozho: To be honest, I assumed Koekiebox was making subtle bathroom humor.

Comment: Serious geekery is always welcome here...but it's nice to chuckle over an SO comment every so often.  :)

Comment: @Koekiebox no need... `close` will flush it. Also ` flush()` is redundant when using `filewriter`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

According to coderanch.com, if we combine the answers we get:

FileWriter is the character representation of IO. That means it can be used to write characters. Internally FileWriter would use the default character set of the underlying OS and convert the characters to bytes and write it to the disk.

PrintWriter & FileWriter.

Similarities

1. Both extend from Writer.
2. Both are character representation classes, that means they work with characters and convert them to bytes using default charset.

Differences

1. FileWriter throws IOException in case of any IO failure, this is a checked exception.
2. None of the PrintWriter methods throw IOExceptions, instead they set a boolean flag which can be obtained using checkError().
3. PrintWriter has an optional constructor you may use to enable auto-flushing when specific methods are called. No such option exists in FileWriter.
4. When writing to files, FileWriter has an optional constructor which allows it to append to the existing file when the "write()" method is called.

Difference between PrintStream and OutputStream: Similar to the explanation above, just replace character with byte.

PrintWriter has following methods :

```
close()
flush()
format()
printf()
print()
println()
write()
```

and constructors are :

```
File (as of Java 5)
String (as of Java 5)
OutputStream
Writer
```

while FileWriter having following methods :

```
close()
flush()
write()
```

and constructors are :

```
File
String
```

Link: http://www.coderanch.com/t/418148/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/Information-PrintWriter-FileWriter

Comment: A very poor quality answer. 'FileWriter is the character representation of I/O ' is meaningless. All Writers write characters. FileWriter writes *to a file.* PrintWriter writes to a nested writer, which can be a FileWriter.

Comment: I currently have a PrintWriter throwing an IOException.

Answer (score 12):

Both of these use a `FileOutputStream` internally:

```
public PrintWriter(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
this(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file))),
     false);
}



public FileWriter(File file) throws IOException {
super(new FileOutputStream(file));
}
```

but the main difference is that PrintWriter offers special methods:

> Prints formatted representations of
>   objects to a text-output stream. This
>   class implements all of the print
>   methods found in PrintStream. It does
>   not contain methods for writing raw
>   bytes, for which a program should use
>   unencoded byte streams.
>
> Unlike the PrintStream class, if
>   automatic flushing is enabled it will
>   be done only when one of the println,
>   printf, or format methods is invoked,
>   rather than whenever a newline
>   character happens to be output. These
>   methods use the platform's own notion
>   of line separator rather than the
>   newline character.

Comment: PrintWriter only uses a FileOutputStream when you're writing to a File.

Comment: @EJP I never said otherwise. But this question is in the context of writing files

Answer (score 7):

A `PrintWriter` has a different concept of error handling. You need to call `checkError()` instead of using try/catch blocks.

Answer (score 3):

`PrintWriter` doesn't throw `IOException`.You should call `checkError()` method for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

**The `java.io.PrintWriter` in Java5+ allowed for a convenience method/constructor that writes to file.
From the Javadoc;**

Creates a new PrintWriter, without automatic line flushing, with the specified file. This convenience constructor creates the necessary intermediate OutputStreamWriter, which will encode characters using the default charset for this instance of the Java virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

just to provide more info related to FLUSH and Close menthod related to FileOutputStream

flush() ---just makes sure that any buffered data is written to disk  flushed compltely and ready to write again to the stream (or writer) afterwards.

close() ----flushes the data and closes any file handles, sockets or whatever.Now connection has been lost and you can't write anything to outputStream.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that java.io.FileWriter relies on the default character encoding of the platform makes it rather useless to me. You should never assume something about the environment where your app will be deployed.