# FileIO to .csv files

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, csv

So I'm working on a project for school. I need to record the data from my arrays into Excel and I'm having some trouble. This is part of my experiment class.

```
public static void exp(Params params) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String temp;
        for (temp = ""; temp.isEmpty(); temp = s.nextLine()) {
            System.out.println("Enter a directory and filename that you want the results to be saved under.");
            System.out.println("(If no directory is specified, results will be in same folder as the jar.)");
        }

        params.setFileName(temp);
        s.close();
        System.out.println("Executing...");
        long timeArray[] = new long[params.getFinalSize() / params.getIncrement()];
        int counter = 0;
        SortFacade facade = new SortFacade();
        for (int n = params.getInitialSize(); n <= params.getFinalSize(); n += params.getIncrement()) {
            System.out.println((new StringBuilder("Array of size: ")).append(n).toString());
            long tempTime = 0L;
            for (int j = 0; j < params.getNumTrials(); j++) {
                System.out.println((new StringBuilder("Trial #")).append(j + 1).toString());
                params.generateArrays(n, params.getTypeList());
                tempTime += facade.sort(params);
            }

            timeArray[counter] = tempTime / (long) params.getNumTrials();
            counter++;
        }

        params.setTimeArray(timeArray);
        System.out.println("Times for each array size(ms): " + Arrays.toString(timeArray));
        System.out.println("Writing to File...");
        System.out.println("Complete.");
    }

}
```

Comment: *"I'm having some trouble"* - Really?  Do explain

Comment: What would I need to do in order to record the data from these experiments into .csv files? I can send you all my code if you want.

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Answer (score 0):

Start with  [Filewriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)  
Make sure what you write is comma-delimeted and saved as a .csv 
Also, take a look at  [this existing question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073980/java-writing-strings-to-a-csv-file)