# Returning a CSV file in java using "public File"

Tags: java, csv

I have to implement a digitSquareSum() method which I have implemented as the following:

```
 public int digitSquareSum(int n) {
    int total;
    if (n < 10) {
        total = (int) Math.pow(n, 2);
        return total;
     } else {
        total = (int) ((Math.pow((n %10), 2)) + digitSquareSum(n/10));
        return total;
     }
}
```

Now, I want to make a method which will return a Java File object for a CSV file populated with digitSquareSum from 1-500 with the following format:

```
public File questionOne() throws Exception {
    //code here
}
```

So the file should look like
1,1
2,4
.
.
500,25

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: Use a `java.io.FileWriter`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Writing strings to a CSV file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073980/java-writing-strings-to-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go :

```
public File questionOne() throws Exception {
    File file = new File("C:\\your\\path\\here", "your_file_name.csv");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    for (int i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
        bw.append(i + "," + digitSquareSum(i) + "\n");
    }
    bw.close();
    return file;
}
```