# Is there a reason to get the file name of a path before converting it to a file?

Tags: java, path, nio

Someone answered [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45110326/4077150) using `path.getFileName().toFile()` instead of just `path.toFile()`. Is there a reason for that or should I use just `path.toFile()`?

Comment: Why not ask the person who answered your question?

Comment: Sorry. I'll do like you said next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific situation it was `path.getFileName().toFile().getName()` in this case `path.toFile().getName()` will give you same result.

But generally speaking `path.getFileName().toFile()` and `path.toFile()` will return different files.

Here small example.

```
    Path path =  FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("foo", "bar", "buzz");
    System.out.println(path.getFileName().toFile());
    System.out.println(path.toFile());
```

Which give us

```
buzz
foo\bar\buzz
```