# PrintWriter vs FileWriter in the following context

Tags: java, filewriter, printwriter

What if in the next bit of code I am going to substitute `(new FileWriter` with `(new PrintWriter`

```
pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter  ("xanaduindeed.txt")));

pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter ("xanaduindeed.txt")));
```

Both of them work fine, however I would like to know which of the two optimize the memory usage. (if either of the two is actually better)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't `pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter("xanaduindeed.txt")));` the same as `pw = new PrintWriter("xanaduindeed.txt");` ?

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle's JVM:

```
public PrintWriter(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName))),
         false);
}
```

`PrintWriter`'s notable characteristic is to flush output on every newline (LF or CR or CRLF). Lowest memory footprint would be a bare `FileWriter`, but buffering gives a notable improvement in I/O performance.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing I'd worry about is exception handling being different for both cases. Check out this older answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759925/printwriter-vs-filewriter-in-java)

In either case though, be careful with the encoding! You're taking yout system's default, so something you write on your computer might be misread in another

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is

```
new PrintWriter ("xanaduindeed.txt")));
```

it uses BufferedWriter internally and writes text to a character-output stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient writing of single characters, arrays, and strings. You dont need to try and optimize it further.