# what is the difference between these two ways of writing to a file in java?

Tags: java, file-io, io, fileoutputstream

I have two implementations below, where the `PrintStream` object wraps either `FileOutputStream` object or `File` object. I get the same thing done with both. Are there any difference between them where one method will not be applicable to write.

```
public class Varags {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("Test.txt");
                         PrintStream p1=new PrintStream( output);
                         p1.println("trying");

            PrintStream p=new PrintStream( new File("test2.txt"));
            p.println("trying");
}
}
```

Are there other way of writing to file that is better than these?

Thanks

Comment: Helpful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759925/printwriter-vs-filewriter-in-java

Comment: *"Are there other way of writing to file that is better than these?"* - Yes, but it depends what you mean by better, and what you are trying to write.  (If you only want to write a single string to the file, "better" is irrelevant!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no difference. According to the Javadocs the `File` version creates an `OutputStreamWriter` anyways, and is only included for convenience.

In many cases, using a `Writer` is better for plain text input. If you're working with raw byte data then streams such as `FileInputStream`, `FileOutputStream`, etc. will be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

PrintStream provides some convenience methods for writing text to a file. To get more control about writing characters to a file, use PrintWriter.

OutputStream is used to write bytes (pure data, not just text) to a file.