# Java FileWritter write to new line each time

Tags: java, filewriter

```
    try {
        File file = new File(filepath+"temp.txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(input+"\n");
        bw.close();
        fw.close();
    } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Every time the user enters something, I want it recorded into a text file. The problem is that every time the user enters something, its recorded on the same line. How do I edit this part of my code to write to a file, then start a new line so that next time it writes to a new line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5760019/738746

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use that

```
bw.write(input);
bw.newLine();
```

Try to google first or it is even better read the javadocs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Comment: I must 'wait another 31 seconds to accept an answer', hold on tight ;) thanks for helping again