# How to write an int to the same file we are reading from?

Tags: java

I am trying to read from a file and then writing back to that same while while appending it.

The file to be read has `5,10` and after writing, it the file should have `5,10"\n" 15`.

But instead of that it has `5,10"\n" SI`.

here is my source code -

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;


public class Ash  {



public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

File file = new File("ashray.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
Scanner input = new Scanner(reader);

    String str = input.nextLine();

    String [] sc = str.split(",");

    int x = Integer.parseInt(sc[0]);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(sc[1]);
    int z = x+y;
    input.close();

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file,true);
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);     
    writer.write(Integer.toString(z));

    fw.close();     

   }    
}
```

Comment: you need to close the reader..

Comment: @AnoopLL - no he doesn't.  Closing the Scanner closes it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `PrintWriter`

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-8");
writer.println("print content here");
writer.close();
```

Comment: why can't i use filewriter wrapped in buffered writer?

Comment: You can but you have to know hoe Buffer write to file. how does he converter content. (utf-8? ansi?)

Comment: can u please tell me how to write with filewriter and buffered writer?

Comment: Read this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759925/printwriter-vs-filewriter-in-java

Comment: if i write on some other file its writing `15` but not on the same file. why is it so?

Comment: Since the reader is open. close it and write to it and it will be fine.
You need to close it before you can write to it if you have it opened in the reader.

Comment: thanks! ..so i guess just closing bufferedreader won't work i need to close filereader !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are closing the `FileWriter` rather than the `BufferedWriter`.  This means that your application is exiting with unwritten characters in the `BufferedWriter`'s buffer.

Solution:  change

```
 fw.close();
```

to

```
 writer.close();
```

Closing the `BufferedWriter` is going to close the `Writer` that it wraps.  The javadoc says so.

(You don't need to close the `Reader`.  Closing the `Scanner` will close the source that it wraps.  And besides, neither is strictly necessary in this context.  But see below.)

---

Also note that if this was production code, it would be advisable to use *try with resources* to ensure that the file descriptors were always closed, irrespective of how the method terminated.  The issue is that if the method terminated because an exception was thrown, you could skip over the statements that close the `Reader` or `Writer` stacks.  That could lead to a resource leak and unexpected errors when opening files ... later on.